# ORA-01017: odbc invalid username and password error - Oracle connectivity issue

Tags: windows, odbc, informatica, informatica-powercenter, oracle19c

I have created an user stg in Oracle (19c) inside a new pluggable database - DATADB

Now, I can login to the user easily from sqlplus or sqldeveloper with normal password. But not from ODBC. I am getting following error :

```
ORA-01017: invalid username / password; logon denied
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPpnT.png)

To solve this problem, I have gone through several articles and many of them suggested to change sec_case_sensitive_login to false

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = false;

Session altered.

SHOW PARAMETER SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON;

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE 
------------------------ ------- ----- 
sec_case_sensitive_logon boolean FALSE
```

But I am still getting same error as above in ODBC, and after changing the parameter, now I am unable to login using sqldeveloper or sqlplus. When I again set it to True,

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = True;
```

I do not get any error now in sqldeveloper or sqlsplus. Overall, I am not able to use ODBC.

Please help!

Comment: Can you pls try using infa provided data direct odbc for oracle driver?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have tried using informatica provided driver, odbc not working. I can create session task, run it and populate data into the table. As informatica relational connection to oracle using service name is working. But ODBC connection is the only issue. I have to manually create source, target structures into informatica.

Comment: Can you check if you can use some other user like admin user etc. ? You may have already tested but just saying.

Comment: Hi Koushik, I do have access to admin user even the root container

Comment: did you configure the connection in the odbc.ini file? path: $INFA_HOME/ODBCX/odbc.ini